# In my exame of discrete math there was a question "Let $X$ be a set (finite or not finite). Prove that $|X| < |P(X)|$, $P(X)$ is the set of parts of X

Tags: combinatorics, induction

I used induction to make that proof
$|X| = n$, $|P(X)| = 2^n$

For $n = 0$, $1 > 0$, true.

Induction hypothesis: $2^n > n$

Induction thesis: $2^{n+1} > n + 1$. We have $2^{n+1} = 2 * 2^n > 2n = n + n > n + 1$ for $n \ge 1$.
At the beginning, I prove that it works for $n = 0$ and at the end for $n \ge 1$ if I put it together I get
that it works for $n \ge 0$.
I got it wrong at the exam, then someone told me that I was supposed to use the Cantor theorem.

Comment: Your argument only works for finite sets but the question concerns both finite and infinite sets.  The problem statement is exactly [Cantor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: Do you know Cantor's proof?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there is an one-to-one map from $X$ to $P(X)$ so $|X| \leq |P(X)|$. Now we will prove there is no surjective map from $X$ to $P(X)$ for any $X$ which will prove that this inequality is strict.

Suppose, there is a surjective map $f: X \rightarrow P(X)$. Consider the set $Y=\{x \in X : x \notin f(x) \}$. Let us consider $f^{-1}(Y)$, let us say $z\in f^{-1}(Y)$. So $f(z)=Y$, now let us see if $z \in Y$, if so then $z \notin f(z) =Y$, if $z \notin Y$ then $z \in f(z)=Y$ in both these cases we find contradictions. So our assumption that there is a surjective map from $X$ to $P(X)$ is wrong.